# How to fomalize compositions?

Tags: logic, proof-writing

I'm trying to formalize the Godel's Incompleteness Theorems and their proofs via Coq, referring to [this lecture note](https://web.yonsei.ac.kr/bkim/goedel.pdf).

As one has already defined the natural numbers by zero and successor, I want to define compositions inductively.

This is my idea on formalizing compositions:

- $\mathtt{load}$ : For $f : \omega^{1 + n} \to \omega$ and $g : \omega^{n} \to \omega$, the function $ \mathtt{load} \; n \; f \; g $ correponds to $$ \left( x_{0} , \cdots , x_{n - 1} \right) \mapsto f \left( x_{0} , \cdots , x_{n - 1} , g \left( x_{0} , \cdots , x_{n - 1} \right) \right) . $$

```
Example load_example1 (f : w -> w -> w -> w) (g : w -> w -> w) :
  load 2 f g = (fun x0 : w => fun x1 : w => f x0 x1 (g x0 x1)).
Proof.
  reflexivity.
Qed.
```

- $\mathtt{call}$ : For $f : \omega^{n} \to \omega$, the function $\mathtt{call} \; m \; n \; f $ correponds to $$ \left( x_{0} , \cdots, x_{m + n - 1} \right) \mapsto f \left( x_{m} , \cdots , x_{m + n - 1} \right) . $$

```
Example call_example1 (f : w -> w -> w -> w) :
  call 2 3 f = (fun x0 : w => fun x1 : w => fun x2 : w => fun x3 : w => fun x4 : w => f x2 x3 x4).
Proof.
  reflexivity.
Qed.
```

- $\mathtt{proj}$: The function $\mathtt{proj} \; n$ correponds to $$ \left( x_{0} , \cdots , x_{n} \right) \mapsto x_{0} . $$

```
Example proj_example1 : 
  proj 3 = (fun x0 : w => fun x1 : w => fun x2 : w => fun x3 : w => x0).
Proof.
  reflexivity.
Qed.
```

My question is this: What is the rule that translates a given composition to the combinations of the above three functions?

I have obtained some examples of translations by my hands:

```
Example composition_example1 (f : w -> w -> w) (g1 : w -> w -> w) (g2 : w -> w -> w) :
  (fun x0 : w => fun x1 : w => f (g1 x0 x1) (g2 x0 x1)) = load 2 (load 3 (call 2 2 f) (load 3 (load 4 (call 3 2 g2) (call 1 3 (proj 2))) (call 0 3 (proj 2)))) g1.
Proof.
  reflexivity.
Qed.

Example composition_example2 (f : w -> w -> w -> w) (g1 : w -> w -> w) (g2 : w -> w -> w) (g3 : w -> w -> w) :
  (fun x0 : w => fun x1 : w => f (g1 x0 x1) (g2 x0 x1) (g3 x0 x1)) = load 2 (load 3 (load 4 (call 2 3 f) (load 4 (load 5 (call 4 2 g3) (call 1 4 (proj 3))) (call 0 4 (proj 3)))) (load 3 (load 4 (call 3 2 g2) (call 1 3 (proj 2))) (call 0 3 (proj 2)))) g1.
Proof.
  reflexivity.
Qed.

Example composition_example3 (f : w -> w -> w) (g1 : w -> w -> w -> w) (g2 : w -> w -> w -> w) :
  (fun x0 : w => fun x1 : w => fun x2 : w => f (g1 x0 x1 x2) (g2 x0 x1 x2)) = load 3 (load 4 (call 3 2 f) (load 4 (load 5 (load 6 (call 4 3 g2) (call 2 4 (proj 3))) (call 1 4 (proj 3))) (call 0 4 (proj 3)))) g1.
Proof.
  reflexivity.
Qed.
```

I want to describe the translation pattern but cannot, so I'm asking for help.

Answer (score 1):

I was so stupid.

There is an very easy way to define composition inductively:

```
Fixpoint call (m : nat) : forall n : nat, Arity n w -> Arity (m + n) w :=
  match m with
  | 0 => fun n : nat => fun f : Arity n w => f
  | S m' => fun n : nat => fun f : Arity n w => fun r : w => call m' n f
  end
.

Fixpoint load (m : nat) : forall n : nat, Arity (m + S n) w -> Arity m w -> Arity (m + n) w :=
  match m with
  | 0 => fun n : nat => fun f : Arity (S n) w => fun g : w => f g
  | S m' => fun n : nat => fun f : w -> Arity (m' + S n) w => fun g : w -> Arity m' w => fun r : w => load m' n (f r) (g r)
  end
.

Example composition_example1 (f : w -> w -> w -> w) (g1 : w -> w -> w) (g2 : w -> w -> w) (g3 : w -> w -> w) :
  (fun x0 : w => fun x1 : w => f (g1 x0 x1) (g2 x0 x1) (g3 x0 x1)) = load 2 0 (load 2 1 (load 2 2 (call 2 3 f) g1) g2) g3.
Proof.
  reflexivity.
Qed.
```

That is, a solution is to make $\mathtt{call} \; m \; n \; f$ correspond to
$$ \left( x_{0} , \cdots , x_{m + n - 1} \right) \mapsto f \left( x_{m} , \cdots , x_{m + n - 1} \right) $$
for $ f : \omega^{m} \to \omega $ and $\mathtt{load} \; m \; n \; f \; g$ correspond to $$ 
\left( x_{0} , \cdots , x_{m + n - 1} \right) \mapsto f \left( x_{0} , \cdots , x_{m - 1} , g \left( x_{0} , \cdots , x_{m - 1} \right) , x_{m} , \cdots , x_{m + n - 1} \right) $$
for $ f : \omega^{m + \left(1 + n\right)} \to \omega $ and $ g : \omega^{m} \to \omega $.